# Problems with Twitter OmniAuth via Sinatra

Tags: ruby, twitter, oauth, sinatra, omniauth

I'm trying to build a sinatra app that authenticates with Twitter but I'm currently stuck at the point where the app goes to twitter to authenticate but fails & provides me with vague message:

> Something is technically wrong.

I'm really lost where to start trying to debug this problem. Any help would be great.

Auth keys have been replaced with XXX.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'omniauth-twitter'
require 'better_errors'

set :server, 'webrick'
set :bind, '127.0.0.1'
set :port, 3000

configure do
  enable :sessions

  use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :twitter, 'XXXX', 'XXXX'
  end

  use BetterErrors::Middleware
  BetterErrors.application_root = __dir__
end

before do
  pass if request.path_info =~ /^\/auth\//
  redirect to('/auth/twitter') unless current_user
end

get '/auth/twitter/callback' do
  session[:uid] = env['omniauth.auth']['uid']
  redirect to('/')
end

get '/auth/failure' do
end

get '/' do
  'Hello omniauth-twitter!'
  puts env['omniauth.auth']['info']['name']
end

helpers do
  def current_user
    !session[:uid].nil?
  end
end
```

**Callback URL (set on Twitter):** `http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback`

Comment: If you capture the request to Twitter could you replay the request using cURL and see if you get a better error message from Twitter's API?